# RailsのProductionで環境変数の読み込みが行えない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsのproduction環境でENVの環境変数を使うために`/etc/environment`に値を書き込み、`source`コマンドで読み込んだのですが rails console 上で参照できません。何が間違っているのでしょうか？

```
$ echo $GMAIL_ADDRESS
my@example.com
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.1)
[1] pry(main)> ENV['GMAIL_ADDRESS']
=> nil
```

Comment: `GMAIL_ADDRESS` 変数がシェル変数のままで、エクスポートされていないのではないでしょうか？ /etc/environment の書式がどの様になっているのか不明ですが、`export GMAIL_ADDRESS=...` と書く必要がありそうです。ただ、/etc/environment はシステム全体に影響しますので、果たして /etc/environment に記載するのが適切なのかどうか調べた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りシェル変数のままになってしまっていました。`/etc/environment`に関してもアドバイスありがとうございます。ただRailsのサービスを提供するだけのサーバーなのでこのまま行こうと思います。

Comment: 意図的に使っていないかもしれませんが、環境変数を手軽に扱いたい場合は、 [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) を使うと便利です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(コメントより)

`GMAIL_ADDRESS` 変数がシェル変数のままで、エクスポートされていないのではないでしょうか？

`/etc/environment` の書式がどの様になっているのか不明ですが、`export GMAIL_ADDRESS=...` と書く必要がありそうです。ただ、 `/etc/environment` はシステム全体に影響しますので、果たして `/etc/environment` に記載するのが適切なのかどうか調べた方が良いかと思います。